# rails server not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when i'm in cd omruby(the file with all the actual code) it works and runs locally BUT only comes up with the default rails page.

i used to be able to do

cd desktop then

cd omruby

and then run it locally and it would come up with my app but when i go into the file cd desktop it comes up with this error.

```
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:14:in `<class:Application>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Omrails>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: going into the terminal and using the command "rails server" or rails s

Comment: Could you provide more info on your application? Modules, changes you made...

Comment: i'm using windows. will that have anything to do with it? i've read that coding with windows can be problematic

Comment: this is the beginning of my gem file (doesn't let me paste inanymore)  source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.6"

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.5'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre4'

Comment: Please edit your question to paste additional information! You can't nor shouldn't paste long code in a comment.

Comment: why isn't it letting me post code?

Comment: Another thing, this doesn't seem to be the full error. Could you edit your question to add this too?

Comment: i showed someone else this error on another site and they said the same thing but there is legit nothing else, weird

Comment: What i would do is generate a fresh application. Make sure it works, then test that everything works after adding each gem. After each change, test that it works. Like that you will be able to pinpoint the cause of your problem.

You provide too little info.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. Then I reinstalled everything(ruby, rails) and it works now. FYI, my ruby version is 2.2.0 and rails 4.2.0.. This is the link I followed https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/. Hope it helps.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. but i managed to fix my problem. the solution to it was fixing typos in my code. (should pick up a habit to checking before i whinge to other people about my problems) but thanks so much. and excuse my way of talking.